# Error in making cross domain request using jquery for json content

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, jquery

I am trying to call a service which returns the data in json format. I am using `jquery-ajax` request to get that response data.

```
 $('#butCallAjax').click(function () {
         $.ajax({
             url: 'my service url',
             type: 'GET',
             data: {},
             success: function (data) {
                 if (data == "success") {
                     alert('request sent!');
                 }
             },
             error: function () {
                 alert('error');
             }
         });
     });
```

using this code I am getting error

> Origin 'servername' is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Then I found some answers here and solved that by using `dataType:'jsonp'` in the request But when I use this `dataType:'jsonp'` then I am getting this error

> Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token :

I understand that this is because of Service is returning `'json'` instead of `jsonp`.

So I am not able to figured it out that how to call a service that returns the json content and taking care of cross domain request.

[Js Fiddle Try](http://jsfiddle.net/NXUJU/)

Comment: Why are you using ajax and not normal jsonP?

Comment: Your service isn't returning JSONP. JSONP != JSON

Comment: @KevinB yes my service is returning the `json` content.

Comment: If you don't make it instead return jsonp, it's not going to work.

Comment: Does the service support jsonp? Do you own the service?

Comment: @Sachin After looking at your fiddle, it appears that the remove service doesn't support jsonp. If you are the developer of that service, you need to do some research about how to implement jsonp for your service.

Answer (score 0):

That doesnt answer your question directly but its also a way to achieve what you're trying:

You can use:

```
/* java side: */
$.getJSON("URL?some_call_back_function=?", dataToPass, function(data){
// do whatever you like..
});

/* php side: */
 if(isset($_GET['some_call_back_function']) && $_GET['some_call_back_function'] != ''){
     $someJsonToReturn = array('Something'=> "something");
     echo $_GET['some_call_back_function'].'('.json_encode($someJsonToReturn ).')';
 }
```

i hope that helps. i use that usually when i want cross domain.

here is the jquery API for it:
[getJson API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: it is giving me the same error. Can you make a jsfiddle example with my service url. May be I'm missing something

Comment: please past here how your php looks, actually let me show you how its suppose to look:

Comment: you can look into my fiddle example

Comment: In my above example you see how i encapsulated whatever json i wanted to return inside the callback function.

Comment: @NetaMeta You're on the right track but a few comments.. 1) Your comment should say "javascript" side. 2) jQuery sends the callback parameter as "callback", so I would use that to simplify things. 3) Your server-side code should output raw json if the callback isn't supplied.

Comment: @NetaMeta I am not familier with `php` and I am just using html page.So just want to display the json data.

Comment: jason P, yap that was 1) was a mistake, will correct it now. 2) yea i know i just change it to make sure he see, and 3) you must return the callback in your response or it simply wont work.. Thanks for the correction @sachin if you don't have control of the other server, and its just an API, you are trying to access, i think you'll have to use something else, cURL or something alike. i think

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a cross domain call which fails.

I have modified your jsFiddle and added

```
async: false,
cache:false
```

Plus added errorObject parameter to the "Error" in ajax.

you can see my changes **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/NXUJU/)**

The answer I got now was "network error dom exception 19".

DOM Exception 19 refers to a "Network Error".

**Is the URL that you are contacting in your Ajax call available?**

Cross domain requests are possible **if the server supports it!** Before making the actual GET/POST call, the browser issues an OPTIONS call to the server to check whether it supports cross domain requests. Check if the server that you are contacting supports cross domain requests.

For more details on cross domain requests refer to this article which is very helpful:
[using CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-introduction)